# calculate the sum of series and accuracy python

Tags: python, math

1 /1∙2 + 1/ 2∙3 + 1/ 3∙4 + ⋯ + 1 / (+1) +... ( find the sum of series and then find the accuracy according to formula given in the picture below)

```
def sum(n):
i = 1.1
s = 1/1.2
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    s = s + 1 / i;
return s;
n = 5
print("Sum is", round(sum(n), 6))
```

Here is the formula for finding the accuracy

[image]

```
 1 0.1      0.637464
 2 0.001    0.685288
 3 0.0001   0.685782
 4 0.000001 0.685848
```

Comment: `s = 1/1.2`: are you serious ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking why your code isn't working. In that case, here's the working code.

```
def sum(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum += 1 / (i*(i+1))

    return sum
```

Comment: After returning sum up , need to find the accuracy with the formula from image.

Comment: @NiloyBasak What do you mean accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question... You mean you want to write that formula From the picture in Python code?

I believe it is:

```
a=0
for i in range(1, n+1):
    a = a + ((i+1)**0.5) / (i*e)**i
```